# How to show that $P(X_{n} \geq n$ $i.o.) = 0$, given $E(X_{i}) = 0$ and $E((X_{i})^{2})=1$ for $i=1,2,3...$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, expectation

I'm struggling with the following problem (Exercise 4.5.16 in Rosenthal's probability book):

Let $X_{1}, X_{2},...$ be defined jointly on some probability space, with $E(X_{i}) = 0$ and $E((X_{i})^{2})=1$ for all $i$. Prove that $P(X_{n} \geq n$ $ i.o) = 0$.

My idea was to use the Borel-Cantelli Lemma and argue that $\sum P(X_{n} \geq n) < \infty$, but I'm stuck trying to estimate $P(X_{n} \geq n)$.

Comment: $P(X>\lambda)\le P(|X|>\lambda)\le\lambda^{-2}\Bbb EX^2$.

Comment: Thanks! I can see how the claim I want to prove follows from what you've written, but I'm not exactly sure how to prove those inequalities. Would you mind spelling it out a bit more pedantically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X_n$ is centered, by Chebychev inequality we have
$$
\mathrm{Pr}[X_n\ge n] \le \frac{\mathrm{Var}(X_n)}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n^2}.
$$
Then we obtain
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}\mathrm{Pr}[X_n\ge n]\le \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\zeta(2)<\infty.
$$
The claim follows by Borel Cantelli Lemma I.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. Is there an argument that doesn't appeal to Chebychev's inequality? At this point in the book, Chebychev's inequality hasn't been proved.

Comment: You need _some_ inequality saying $P(X_n>n)$ is less than something. And that has to be in terms of what you're given. It's hard to see how that could be simpler than using Chebyshev. The version we need here is trivial: Let $E$ be the event $X>\lambda$. Then $\Bbb EX^2=\int X^2dP\ge\int_EX^2dP\ge\lambda^2P(E)$.

Comment: Thanks again, David! That's very simple and clear. The section that comes immediately after this exercise proves Markov's and Chebychev's inequalities, so I assume the exercise is meant to illustrate a simple case, using just the argument you give.